# Android linearLayout problem

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

This is my first post here, I was stuck with linearlayout, I have linearlayout(horizontal)  with 3 buttons in it of which I set the third button layout_weight=1 so it takes up the whole space in linearlayout this is pretty much working properly.

But when I put this layout in HorizontalScrollview the weight property doesnt works for me,
what I want is to display two button horizontally on whole screen width and when scrolled third button should appear taking up the whole width of screen hiding both the buttons but its not happening.

Regard's
Saurabh Agnihotri

Comment: You should use a ViewFlipper with 3 sections so each button will be on it's own view.

Comment: Can you post a small picture / link to picture explaining your desired bahavior? Sounds a little bit non-standard behavior. Esp the "when scrolling" part. Maybe just use fix widths or adjust the widths in `onResume`

Comment: any other idea this is not the thing I wanted

Comment: If you follow the link the part where header is written shows two view namely BPM and master vol when user scroll on right it shows another view edit destails which occupies the whole space occupied by both the views http://spinfuse.com/beta/spinfuse-v1.0-beta-manual/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cant do it with horizontal scroll view.
You can do one thing.. take a view flipper and take two layout in it. in one layout there will be two buttons by giving its weight as 1. and in the second layout put a button and give its width as fill_parent. 
Then use gesture listener to move the view flippers layouts.
Then it will look like horizontal scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

You could also remove the linear inside the horizontal and put a table instead with three buttons in one row and two blanks in another so the table sees the third as overflow and feels the need to scroll... You will prbably need to mess around with weights but should work.